# How to know the structure (body) of rest api azure POST request?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

i am new at rest api azure and i dont know how to get correct body template of policy.
For example i used :
`GET https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/policy/types?api-version=7.0`
and the response are types of policies which i can use but how do i know the construction of the request body? Like this one:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "isBlocking": false,
  "type": {
    "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd"
  },
  "settings": {
    "minimumApproverCount": 4,
    "creatorVoteCounts": false,
    "scope": [
      {
        "repositoryId": "a957e751-90e5-4857-949d-518cf5763394",
        "refName": "refs/heads/master",
        "matchKind": "exact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Where should I find those request body templates? :(
Resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP

Comment: Did you review the documentation?

Comment: of course, i am trying to find it for two days but microsoft documentation is pain...

Comment: Please update your question to include what resources you are using as a point of reference.

Comment: Please explain what specific difficulties you're encountering or what is unclear about the examples provided in the documentation. Explain what you're trying to implement and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Those examples are good for those specific cases, for example i need to set up a POST request which will set up "minimumApproverCount": 1 (that is easy), but also second checkbox would be checked - "prohibit the most recent pusher from approving their own changes" or i need to set this policy : Prevent too push the output folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally made it, it was very hard and i dont understand why Microsoft has so bad documentation.... i had to made it by sending randoms request and look at the elements how the names are... so bad so much time spend...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you could `list` or `get` the repo policy correctly, you could use the parameter configuration part of the returning result as the request body in creating the policy with `post` method.

[rest api to list the branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=5.1
```

with optional parameter

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations?scope={scope}&policyType={policyType}&api-version=5.1
```

You could check the templates below for different configurations in [Policy template examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#examples).

> ***Examples***
>
> Approval count policy
>
> Build policy
>
> Example policy
>
> Git case enforcement policy
>
> Git maximum blob size policy
>
> Merge strategy policy
>
> Work item policy

If you still don't know how to compose the request body, you could also share your scenario.